# remove lines from output in bash that contains a huge amount of possibilities

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I'm trying to filter lines for a big txt file (around 10GB) bashed on prefix of called number only when the `direction` column equals `2`.

This is the format of the file that i'm getting from pipe (from a different script)

```
caller_number=34234234324, clear_number=982545345435, direction=1, ...
caller_number=83479234234, clear_number=348347384533, direction=2, ...
```

Of cause this is just an example data but the actual file contains many other columns but I want to only filter the `clear_number` column based on `direction` so this is enough.

I want to remove lines that do not contain a list of prefixes, so for example here I would do that with grep with the following:

```
grep -vP 'clear_number=(?!(2207891|22034418|22074450|220201677|220240574|220272183|220722988|220723276|220751152|220774457|220794227|220799141|2202000425|2202000939|2202000967)).*direction=2'
```

This works beautifully. The only problem is that the number of prefixes that I get is sometimes around 10K-50K, this is a lot of prefixes, and if I try to do that using `grep`
I get `grep: regular expression is too large`.

Any ideas how else to resolve it using Bash commands?

**update**

example.. lets say i have the following:

```
caller_number=34234234324,     clear_number=982545345435, direction=1
caller_number=83479234234,     clear_number=348347384533, direction=2
caller_number=2342334324,      clear_number=5555345435,   direction=1
caller_number=034082394234324, clear_number=33335345435,  direction=1
caller_number=83479234234,     clear_number=348347384533, direction=2
caller_number=83479234234,     clear_number=444447384533, direction=2
caller_number=83479234234,     clear_number=64237384533, direction=2
```

and my `list.txt` contains:

```
642
3333
534234235
```

so it will only return the line

```
caller_number=83479234234,     clear_number=64237384533, direction=2
```

since clear number starts with `642` and direction=`2`. just in my case it will go over 10GB of text file and return at least 100K of results.

**another update**

i'm sorry i wasn't clear about one more thing. i get the lines from a pipe command, so i should do `| awk...` on the output i receive form previous commands.

Comment: could you clarify your use of the term 'prefix'?  assume the line contains `clear_number=1234567890`, would a matching prefix be `12345` or would the matching prefix need to be `1234567890`?  tripleee's answer addresses the former (`12345`) while Wiktor's (current) answer addresses the latter (ie, 'prefix' must be an exact match for `1234567890`)

Comment: @markp-fuso - oh nice observation. yeah prefix means prefix means it starts with that number, it's not the full number. i'll send him a comment.

Comment: @ufk, could you please do add list.txt in your question too so that we get better understanding of question, thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 - updated main post.

Comment: here's a [sed-based answer](https://superuser.com/a/719118) with a couple ideas that may work, too

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following. Since OP has changed samples so adding code as per that now.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  arr[$0]
  next
}
match($0,/clear_number=[^,]*/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART+13,RLENGTH-13)
  for(i in arr){
    if(index(val,i)==1 && $NF=="direction=2,"){
      print
      next
    }
  }
}
' list.txt  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                  ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR==NR{               ##Checking condition if FNR==NR which will be TRUE when list.txt is being read.
  arr[$0]              ##Creating arr array with index of current line.
  next                 ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
match($0,/clear_number=[^,]*/){  ##Using match to match regex for clear_match till 1st occurrence of comma here.
  val=substr($0,RSTART+13,RLENGTH-13)  ##Creating val which has substring of matched regex.
  for(i in arr){       ##Traversing through arr here.
    if(index(val,i)==1 && $NF=="direction=2,"){ ##Checking condition of index AND last field is direction=2 then do following.
      print            ##Printing current line here.
      next             ##next will skip all further statements from here.
    }
  }
}
' list.txt  Input_file ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Comment: SO outage is happening in between, so I will try to add explanation as soon as I get complete page loaded not sure this comments gets posted or not.

Comment: hi. your example works, two things missing, you don't address 'direction=2' and i get the data from a pipe not from a static file.

Comment: @ufk, I have edited my code now, that should work for you, let me know how it goes cheers.

Comment: @ufk, so list file is data which you are getting from another program? since you have mentioned you have huge size files, I would suggest you can create a output file(list file) from your first command and then run this awk command separately to avoid performance issues(since I are not sure what that program is doing).

Comment: i didn't understand the substr($0,RSTART+13,RLENGTH-13). didn't understand why +13 and -13. can you explain it please ?

Comment: @ufk, actually my original code was to use `sub`(substitution to remove everything till `=`); which I edited as per fellow awk contributor's advise, doing `substr($0,RSTART+13,RLENGTH-13)` will do the same-thing, basically, removing all the unnecessary stuff from value `clear_number=982545345435`, this will remove clear_number of it. Basically it means remove first 13 characters from matched value by regex. Let me know in case of any queries here, cheers.

Comment: $NF=="direction=2" needs to be $NF=="direction=2," besides that everything works. thanks

Answer (score 7):

You may try this `awk` also:

```sh
your_command |
awk '
FNR == NR {
   rexp["=" $1]
   next
}
$3 == "direction=2" {
   for (s in rexp)
      if (index($2, s)) {
         print
         next
      }
}' list.txt -

caller_number=83479234234,     clear_number=64237384533, direction=2
```

Comment: Using `index($2, s)` is much much faster than `$2 ~ s` when I tested

Answer (score 6):

You can use `awk` to read in the prefixes and filter out lines using

```sh
... | awk -F'[,=[:space:]]+' 'FNR==NR {hash[$0]; next} $6 == 2 {for (key in hash) { if (index($4, key) == 1) { print; next } }}' list.txt - > outputfile
```

The `[,=[:space:]]+` is the field delimiter regex that matches one or more commas, equal signs and whitespace chars.

The `FNR==NR {hash[$0]; next}` parts reads in the contents of `list.txt` with prefixes, each on a separate line.

The `$6 == 2` requires Field 6 (direction) to be equal to `2`.

Then, `{for (key in hash) { if (index($4, key) == 1) { print; next } }}'` tries to find a `hash` value that is a prefix of current Field 4 and prints the line if found and proceeds to the next line.

Comment: This works, but be careful, this expects that direction=2 is always in the third field.

Comment: @kvantour That is a good observation, that should speed it up more.

Comment: @markp-fuso mentioned something that is correct. it's not a full match it's a a prefix match, means number starts with the numbers on the list

Comment: @ufk It is easy to fix.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - if you can show what you changed to allow prefix and not full match it would be great. trying to understand you solution and not just copy/paste it.

Comment: @ufk You can use `index(<field_id>, <value_to_check>) == 1` check to see if a field starts with some value.

Comment: you added the index on the direction column instead of of the clear number column no ?

Comment: @ufk That is what I understood. So, it is the `clear_number=` value must start with the prefix?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233510/discussion-between-ufk-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Answer (score 3):

Closer to what you were originally doing -
(To be clear, this approach is probably not the best for such large datasets, but someone with smaller files might benefit.)

edit your `list.txt` to be *patterns* instead of just prefix strings.
If I use

```
clear_number=123.*direction=2
clear_number=03408.*direction=2
clear_number=4567890.*direction=2
```

and

```
caller_number=34234234321,     clear_number=982545345435, direction=1
caller_number=83479234232,     clear_number=123347384533, direction=2
caller_number=2342334323,      clear_number=5555345435,   direction=1
caller_number=834792394234324, clear_number=03408345435,  direction=1
caller_number=56779234235,     clear_number=348347384533, direction=2
caller_number=83479234236,     clear_number=456789084533, direction=2
caller_number=83479234237,     clear_number=64237384533,  direction=2
```

Then I get this:

```
$: grep -f list.txt x
caller_number=83479234232,     clear_number=123347384533, direction=2
caller_number=83479234236,     clear_number=456789084533, direction=2
```

So reversing the match -

```
$: grep -vf list.txt x
caller_number=34234234321,     clear_number=982545345435, direction=1
caller_number=2342334323,      clear_number=5555345435,   direction=1
caller_number=834792394234324, clear_number=03408345435,  direction=1
caller_number=56779234235,     clear_number=348347384533, direction=2
caller_number=83479234237,     clear_number=64237384533,  direction=2
```

Converting `list.txt` from

```
642
3333
534234235
```

to

```
clear_number=642.*direction=2
clear_number=3333.*direction=2
clear_number=534234235.*direction=2
```

only takes

```
$: sed -i.bak 's/^/clear_number=/; s/$/.*direction=2/;' list.txt
```

which will make a backup, too.

Comment: that's actually beautiful :) gonna try that too

Comment: It might not be as fast, which can matter on really big files, but it's pretty easy to understand.

Comment: ah for some reason i thought it would be faster. anyone thanks a lot for showing me that this is possible. i got a lot of new information today from my question :)

Comment: considering OP mentioned `around 10K-50K`, this would not be a good solution

Comment: Yeah, `grep` is pretty optimized, but for a situation this specific it's likely to take a long time looping over every record.

Comment: Another (similarly messy) approach, if you have a big enough command buffer: `grep -Ev "clear_number=($(echo $(<list.txt.bak) |sed 's/ /|/g')).*direction=2" file` - this can actually work, but a more programmatically targeted solution is going to be faster, and I wouldn't assume you could create a command 10k bytes long...

Answer (score 3):

Here's a much faster solution by changing how the inner loop works. This also uses code from [RavinderSingh13](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67887617) and [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67886269/4082052) answers.

```
FNR==NR{ arr[$0]; next }

$3=="direction=2,"{
    val=substr($2,14)
    for(i=1; i<length(val); i++)
        if(substr(val,1,i) in arr){
            print
            next
        }
}
```

- The inner loop goes over the digits of `clear_number` instead of looping over every key in `arr`. So, instead of looping 10K-50K times, you loop only upto length of the digits, which is about 12 max as per given samples.

  - First time, this loop will have one character from start, next time it will have two characters from the start and so on.
  - `i<length(val)` is used instead of `i<=length(val)` since the last character will be `,`.
- `$3=="direction=2,"` is compared first (this saves all the looping if not matched)
- `match($0,/clear_number=[^,]*/)` isn't needed because `$2` already has this string

Save the above code as `script.awk` and use it as:

```sh
... | mawk -f script.awk list.txt
```

**Note** that I've also used `mawk` in the above code. This version of `awk` is less featured compared to say `GNU awk` but gives better performance. I checked the results with version `1.3.4` and it gave same result as `GNU awk`.

If you don't have `mawk`, then you can use `LC_ALL=C awk` instead of `mawk` in the above command. See [What does LC_ALL=C do?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87745/what-does-lc-all-c-do) for details.

Here's a sample timing result (using `mawk`):

```sh
$ wc data.txt
500000  1500000 36000000 data.txt
$ wc list.txt
12000 12000 73382 list.txt
```

- `0m57.477s` --> anubhava's solution, but with `index($2,s)` instead of `$2 ~ s`
- `0m59.975s` --> RavinderSingh13's solution, but with `$NF=="direction=2,"` compared first
- `1m1.578s` --> Wiktor Stribiżew's solution
- `0m0.271s` --> this solution

Comment: looks promising. thanks a lot, i'll take a look and compare peformance

Answer (score 2):

You can refactor your big regex into a `sed` script instead.  Then the only resource limit really is how much memory you have available for `sed`.

If I am guessing correctly what you are trying, the solution might look something like

```sh
sed -e '/direction=2/!b' \
    -e '/clear_number=2207891/!b' \
    -e '/clear_number=22034418/!b' \
    -e '/clear_number=22074450/!b' \
    -e '/clear_number=220201677/!b' \
    -e '/clear_number=220240574/!b' \
    -e '/clear_number=220272183/!b' \
    -e '/clear_number=220722988/!b' \
    -e '/clear_number=220723276/!b' \
    -e '/clear_number=220751152/!b' \
    -e '/clear_number=220774457/!b' \
    -e '/clear_number=220794227/!b' \
    -e '/clear_number=220799141/!b' \
    -e '/clear_number=2202000425/!b' \
    -e '/clear_number=2202000939/!b' \
    -e '/clear_number=2202000967/!b' \
    -e '/clear_number=/d'
```

If one `clear_number` could be the prefix of another, maybe change the regex slightly to make sure the number is followed by a word boundary. From your examples, adding a space before the terminating slash would seem sufficient, though some `sed` versions also support `\>` or `\b` for word boundaries.