# How to find all lines which contain at least one of a set of words as a prefix

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, grep

I have a text file of words, one per line, called A.

I have another text file B.

How can I find all lines in B what have at least one of the words from A as a prefix?

I was hoping to be able to do this from the command line maybe using grep but any other command line solution would be great too.

For example, if A is

```
apple
bob
cheese
```

and B is

```
aple
bob123
ches
```

I would like the line bob123 to be returned.

Comment: Not my downvote, but probably because you didn't add what you tried to solve this yourself. Also, if your input files can be very large, [you can adapt my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67897978/4082052) for a faster solution.

Comment: @Sundeep does that really mean adding code that doesn't work to the question? I am not sure that is always helpful.

Comment: @Anush yep, that is what expected on SO. Not working code can also help to determine what went wrong in your attempt, because there's so many ways in which one can approach to solve a problem. In some cases, you get errors with your code. Including that error message is another way of searching the internet for solution, so that's helpful too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach uses `bash`'s [*process substitution*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html) and `sed` to add a regular expression beginning-of-line `^` anchor to each line of A, and then tells `grep` to use it as a list of regular expressions to search for:

```sh
$ grep -f <(sed 's/^/^/' a.txt) b.txt
bob123
```

Comment: Or in a POSIX friendly shell dialect: `sed 's/^/^/' a.txt | grep -f - -- b.txt`

Comment: @LéaGris The question *is* tagged bash (Though to be fair there's plenty of people who seem to think that all shells are bash no matter what they're actually using.)

Comment: Until they realize it is for MacOS's old Bash 3.2 or Zsh. This is why, unless a Bash specific syntax is really giving a significant advantage over POSIX shell; I try to have the POSIX way in my answers \(at least as an alternative to the Bash syntax); even if it is clearly more complex, tougher to read or less efficient. As you said: `plenty of people who seem to think that all shells are bash no matter what they're actually using`.

Comment: This particular one works on old bash, zsh, ksh93... Everything but sh and maybe (t)csh, fwiw.